# Find the partial derivative

Tags: derivatives

How to find the partial derivative of this function, with respect for x?
$$
h(x,y)=\frac{1}{\ln(e^x+y)}, y>0
$$

Comment: ... with respect to what?

Answer (score 2):

The way I teach students to deal with partial differentiation, in order to keep the "accounting" straight, is to replace with placeholder constant(s) everything involving the variable(s) you are *not* differentiating with respect to, and handle the resulting expression as if it were plain old single-variable differentiation.  (All of the rules you've already learned there still apply.)  Thus, treat

$$  \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \ \  \text{as} \ \ \frac{d}{dx} \ \left[ \frac{1}{\ln(e^x + C)} \right] \ , $$

and then restore the " $  y  $ " appropriately in the expression for the derivative.  Similarly, write

$$  \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} \ \  \text{as} \ \ \frac{d}{dy} \ \left[ \frac{1}{\ln(D + y)} \right] \ , $$

and then restore the " $  e^x   $ " after completing the "$  y-$  differentiation".

Answer (score 0):

Set $u = e^x + y$ and use the chain rule, taking note that

$h(x, y) = (\ln u)^{-1,} \tag{1}$

whence

$\dfrac{\partial h(x, y)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{dh}{du}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}; \tag{2}$

we have

$\dfrac{dh}{du} = -(\ln u)^{-2} u^{-1} \tag{3}$

and

$\dfrac{\partial u(x, y)}{\partial x} = e^x, \tag{4}$

so bringing it all together yields

$\dfrac{\partial h(x, y)}{\partial x} = -(\ln(e^x + y))^{-2} (e^x + y)^{-1}e^x; \tag{5}$

likewise, since

$\dfrac{\partial u(x, y)}{\partial y} = 1, \tag{6}$

$\dfrac{\partial h(x, y)}{\partial y} = -(\ln(e^x + y))^{-2} (e^x + y)^{-1}. \tag{7}$

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***